# Java script bitwize or, negative results?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand something in java script:
I don't understand what exactly does |0 do in java script?
I mean why:

```
a = 2263041392;        
b = 0;        
console.log(a | b);
```

This code give : -2031925904

But this code:

```
a = 373351379;        
b = 0;        
console.log(a | b);
```

Gives: 373351379
??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you use bitwise operators it treats the number as a 32-bit two's complement signed integer.

Comment: The first number overflows into negative numbers.

Comment: but why does it overflow?
what does the or does? how does it increase the number?

Comment: The maximum positive signed 32-bit number is 2,147,483,647. Your first number is larger than that, your second number is smaller.